# How to get products from wishlist using customer id

Tags: php, products, model, wishlist, magento2.3

**Magento 2.3 PHP 7.1**

I trying to get products from customer wishlist in Model but $products array is empty.

```
        $products = [];
        $items = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId(1, true)->getItemCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product['name'] = $item->getProduct()->getName();
            $product['sku'] = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
            array_push($products, $product);
        }
        var_dump($products);
```

How to get products from wishlist in Model using customer id?

Answer (score 0):

You code was correct and nothing to do with this.

[image: Result]

See

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php#L243

On _afterLoad() resource collection of wishlist items, the products collection was already loaded to the wishlist items

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php#L292-L321

So to call the product each item, from foreach loop you could do

```
$item->getProduct()
```

Which attributes will be available for this product?

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/ResourceModel/Item/Collection.php#L295

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/Config.php#L70

And https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Config.php#L410
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Config.php#L430-L446